# Primefaces : Datatable issue. Text of the link vanishes when clicked

Tags: jsf, linker, datatable, primefaces

I have a primefaces datatable on my view and the first column is a h:link which links to the detailed view of the entity that the row represents. The problem is when I click on the h:link the text vanishes before the control is passed on to the details page.
Is this a known problem ? Is this a problem with JSF or Primefaces ?

I am using Primefaces 2.1 version and JSF 2.0.4-b05 version.

Any help would be lot appreciated.

```
<p:dataTable var="it" value="#{backingBean1.deploymentList}" paginator="#{backingBean1.showPagination}" rows="10">
<p:column   width="210" sortBy="#{it.pr}">
    <f:facet name="header">
        <h:outputText value="Product"/>
    </f:facet>
    <h:link outcome="details.jsf?id=${it.id}" includeViewParams="true">
        <h:outputText value="#{it.pr}"/>
    </h:link>
</p:column>
<p:column width="210" sortBy="#{it.status}">
    <f:facet name="header">
        <h:outputText value="Status"/>
    </f:facet>
    <h:outputText value="#{it.status}"/>
</p:column>
<p:column width="170" sortBy="#{it.type}">
    <f:facet name="header">
        <h:outputText value="Type"/>
    </f:facet>
    <h:outputText value="#{it.type}"/>
</p:column>
<p:column  width="260"  parser="date" sortBy="#{it.created}">
    <f:facet name="header">
        <h:outputText value="Last Updated"/>
    </f:facet>
    <h:outputText value="#{it.created}">
    </h:outputText>
</p:column>
<p:column width="370" sortBy="#{it.tag}" >
    <f:facet name="header">
        <h:outputText value="Tag"/>
    </f:facet>
    <h:outputText value="#{it.tag}"/>
</p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

Comment: From your question it's not quite clear what happens when you click on a link. Could you post the dataTable's code?

Comment: Sorry, but there's no link in your code snippet. Did you forget a column?

Comment: yes, I did miss it. Sorry about it. I have put in the missed part.

Answer (score 0):

Just an idea:

This could be caused by css. There is a selector `a:active` that defines the format of a hyperlink if it is clicked. Mayber your css defines this selector with the same color as page or table background.

You could use your browsers dev tools to check which css formats are applied to your link.